# Count caracteres by column and sum

Tags: awk

The purpose is to check that for input file each column contends exactly same digits. compared with reference file..

It is the way i found to check if the format of a file have exactly same structure ( same dig by column )

**ref_file**

```
1111 2222 333 4
```

**file**

```
1266 2233 344 1
1122 3333 444 1
1111 2222 222 1
1112 2220 22  1
1111 2222 222
1111 2222 222 1
```

**The code I try.**

```
dd=`awk ' {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=length($i)}NF' ref_file | awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) j+=$i; print j; j=0 }'`

    awk ' {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=length($i)}NF' file |
      awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) j+=$i; print $0" " j; j=0 }' |
       awk '{if($NF!~'$dd')print $0 " error"}' | wc -l | awk '{if($1>0) print "FILE FORMAT WRONG "}'
```

I believe there is a easy way to do it.

With my code . I count the dig for each column and sum each row, if the total of any row does not match with total dig then the input file has errors. IE, rows 4 and 5.. It is not necessary to print the lines with error. Only if at least one row has not same structure of the reference file.. show msg "FILE format is wrong" Something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Cyrus.. This is the way I found to check if the format of file is correct.. Maybe as u mention just with the total length of row it works..

Comment: This question is very unclear to me at least. Please, try to clarify. Use more examples if needed and add the expected output for those inputs etc. You could use smaller examples too.

Comment: same characters or same number of characters or same unique set of characters or same number of unique character or....? In just column 2 or across all columns or...? Same characters for that column across all rows or same characters for all columns in each row? Same as some predefined value or same as first row or same as each other or...? What's the expected output for the "success" and "failure" cases given your posted sample input? Do you actually need 2 separate input examples - one success and one failure or does that one input sample contain both?

Comment: Gents, I have changed a little the question. to be more clear, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Perhaps even is not necessary the ref_file.. Only to have the total of dig of one row as variable..?

Comment: @OXXO updated my answer accordingly. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to F. Knorr's answer, but uses the ref_file

```
awk '
    NR == FNR { nf = NF; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) len[i] = length($i); next }
    NF != nf { err = FNR; exit }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (len[i] != length($i)) { err = FNR; exit } }
    END { if (err) { print "invalid file format on line", err; exit 1 } }
' ref_file file
```

---

You *almost* had it in your comment: FILENAME is a valid awk variable that holds the name of the *current* file (taken from the given command arguments, or "-" if awk is reading from stdin)

```
END {
    if (err) {print "invalid file format on line", err; exit 1} 
    print "File format correct for :", FILENAME
}
```

Comment: Glenn is there the chance to add to the code the option to print " File format correct for : FILENAME" in case that no errors were found

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have come up with (as far as I understood the question):

```
awk 'NR==1{fields=NF
           for (i = 1; i <= fields; i++)
             cols[i]=length($i)
          }
     NR>1 { if(NF != fields)
              print "line "NR" has a different number of columns"
            else
              for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                if(length($i) != cols[i])
                  print "column "i" in line "NR" has a different length"
          }' t
```

Output:

```
column 3 in line 4 has a different length
line 5 has a different number of columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    a[i]=length($i)
  }
  next
}
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    if (length($i)!=a[i]) {
      printf("error at line %d, column %d.\n%s\n", FNR, i, $0)
      exit
    }
  }
}' ref_file file
```

Output:

```
error at line 4, column 3.
1112 2220 22  1
```